# Exactly why is the size of this struct 32?

Tags: c, linux, struct, embedded-linux

I needed help in finding the size of the struct below

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct bottle{
    float* weight;
    int* qnty;
    char* type;
    char* color;
};

int main(){
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(struct bottle));
    return 0;
}
```

I got the output as 32 but I'm not getting how it derived with that value and I want someone to explain why it is 32.

PS: I'm using a Linux compiler.

Comment: You're on a 64-bit machine.  Each pointer occupies 8 bytes; 4 pointers occupy 32 bytes.  What's the mystery?  What size did you expect and why?

Comment: Please remember to post code that compiles.  I fixed the obvious typos for you — changing commas into semicolons inside the structure definition.  Please be more careful in future.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler for the answer

Comment: Also worth knowing - the size may be larger than you expect for non-pointer member variables, because of padding to keep variables memory address aligned on the boundaries needed for the CPU - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306186/structure-padding-and-packing

Comment: I didn't go through pointers size in struct, so with structure padding I thought the size would be 12 (4 bytes for float, 4 bytes of int, 2 bytes of char + 2 padding) but now I got it cleared. So, pointer takes up 8 bytes no matter what?

Comment: @DaveS Thanks for info! I'm clear with this now

Comment: "pointer takes up 8 bytes no matter what? " - for 64-bit software, yes.  For 32-bit (still common in Windows) it is 4 bytes.  A pointer points to an address in memory, so its size is what is needed to hold a memory address, not the size of the object it is pointing to.  A char* size is 8 bytes and can point to 1 char or 100,000 chars.  It's the page number in a book, not the text on the page.

Comment: Have a google for #pragma pack.  Depending on what you have in the structure, the size can vary depending on the packing alignment.

Comment: As a side note, the address bus does not necessarily have the same width as the maximum data size that the CPU can chew in a single instruction. That just happens to be the case for most 32 bitters and 64 bitters. So "it's 8 bytes because you are on a 64 bit machine" is a bit of an over-simplification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the provided result, I assume you are on a 64-bit machine. This means that your system most probably has a 64-bit address bus, so the addresses it can *address* are 64 bits wide.

Most of the time, C pointers are implemented as direct virtual memory addresses and are the same width as the address bus (in your case, 64 bits).

```
/* 64 bits = 8 bytes */

struct bottle {
    float *weight; /* 8 bytes */
    int *qnty;     /* 8 bytes */
    char *type;    /* 8 bytes */
    char *color;   /* 8 bytes */
};

/* Grand total: 32 bytes */
```

On a 32-bit machine, this would be 16 bytes.

Comment: Re “Since C pointers are memory addresses, on a 64-bit machine any type of pointer will be 64 bits wide”: I have used a C implementation with 32-bit pointers on a 64-bit machine. As specified in the C standard, C pointers are abstract entities. C implementations commonly implement them as direct virtual memory addresses, but this is not required by the C standard and is not always the case. It is even possible for different types of pointers to have different sizes within one C implementation.

Comment: That is true, however I avoided going into too much detail given OP's current knowledge level. I will update my comment to take this into account as well.